# spring boot observability new property missing tags

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

After upgrading my spring applications I can see that the metrics exposed through actuator to Prometheus has changed its tags location in the properties from `metrics.tags` to `observations.key-values` as below. However, after this change only a subset of my metrics gets this additional tag - I can't find any documentation specifying if this change require additional properties or settings - what has changed :)

From:

```
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      application: my-service
```

To:

```
management:
  observations:
    key-values:
      application: my-service
```

Comment: Same here, looks like a Bug which should be reported to Github.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38583)